# not able to work with sub subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

I have an issue.I need to get url like  subdomain2.subdomain1.domain.in/filename .
I created a subdomain2 under sundomain1 in cpanal its is created like subdomain2.sundomain1.domain.in
But I have doubt on how to create in  .htaccess file for sub subdomain.

To give an example:- `articles.mydomain.in` is working whereas `mycity.articles.mydomain.in`
is not working..

Can this be done or what I am doing is wrong? When I googled I came to know that it cannot be done in one website,whereas in another website they have mentioned that it can be done,but not given how  to procees.Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have create this 2 websites in cpanel i'm not sure you need to add a .htaccess file anywhere.

Comment: @ôkio , Ya i have created subdomains from `.htaccess` itself

Answer (score 0):

Your sub sub domain should have its own folder. So you have to put .htaccess file there.

You could check the folder in your apache configuration. (See VirtualHost directive for subdomain2.sundomain1.domain.in).

Config probably located here: 
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/httpd/httpd.conf